# Why are open and simply connected required for $\frac{\delta P}{\delta y} = \frac{\delta Q}{\delta x}$ to imply a conservative field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-fields

A theorem concerning line integrals runs as follows:

[image]

I want to develop some intuition as to why this theorem depends on $D$ being open and simply-connected.

My thoughts:

$D$ being closed (that is, intuitively, if the region had a boundary) should have no bearing on whether $F$ is conservative. A conservative vector field could still exist on boundary points (I can still run around the boundary in two paths from an incident point to a final one and aggregate some equal quantity).

If $D$ were **not** simply connected by, say, containing a hole inside of it, the hole wouldn't be a part of $D$. This means that $\frac{\delta P}{\delta y} = \frac{\delta Q}{\delta x}$  being true still implies a conservative field at all other points (which, collectively form D). Hence, $F$  can still be considered conservative.

Comment: Open is usually asked for the definition of the partial derivatives to make sense.

Comment: Consider the space $Z$ of (say, smooth) fields $Pi + Qj$ with $\partial P/\partial y = \partial Q/\partial x$ throughout $D$ and the space of $B$ of conservative fields on $D$. Although $B\subset Z$, the opposite inclusion doesn't hold in general. The relevant result is that, under sufficiently nice circumstances, the quotient $B/Z$ is the first de Rham cohomology group $H^1(D)$. The definition of this is complicated, but it measures how much $D$ fails to be simply connected. In particular, if $D$ actually is simply connected, then $H^1(D) = 0$; that is, every field in $Z$ is conservative.

Comment: In 2D you can work with somewhat less sophisticated methods by thinking about complex analysis. Basically, if you have a simply connected domain, a closed path in that domain, and a holomorphic function on the domain, then you can homotopically contract the path to a point. The homotopy will not change the value of the integral, and the value of the integral over a point is zero, so the value of the integral over all paths is zero.

Comment: (Cont.) But if you poke a hole in the domain, then you cannot homotopically contract to a point, so this argument fails. For instance, maybe we have $f(z)=1/z$ on the disk punctured at zero. (This is basically Julian's example.) Then the Cauchy integral formula tells us what we get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a somewhat informal idea of what's happening. The relevance of the quantity $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ (this is the magnitude of the curl of $\mathbf{F}$), evaluated at a point $(x,y)$, is that the line integral around a very small closed curve $\gamma$ at $(x,y)$ is approximately $(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y})\cdot (\text{area inside $\gamma$)}$. In particular, if $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$, then the line integral around small enough closed curves is more or less zero.

Now, $\mathbf{F}$ being conservative is equivalent to the line integral of $\mathbf{F}$ around *every* piecewise smooth closed curve being $0$. The problem therefore becomes: if you know the line integral around small enough closed curves is (essentially) zero, can you conclude the same for any closed curve? You could try to do this as follows. Say $\gamma$ is a closed curve; for simplicity, let's imagine it's the boundary of a square, oriented counterclockwise. Divide up the interior $R$ of the square into very small squares. Each small square $S_i$ has a boundary curve $\gamma_i$, oriented counterclockwise. Notice that every edge of a small square is matched with another edge of an adjacent square which is oriented in the opposite direction, *except* for the boundary edges that form $\gamma$. Thus, when we take the sum of the integrals $\int_{\gamma_i} \mathbf{F}$ over all the little curves $\gamma_i$, the contributions from interior edges cancel out and we're left with $\int_{\gamma} \mathbf{F}$.

[image]

On the other hand, the curves $\gamma_i$ were very small, so each term $\int_{\gamma_i} \mathbf{F}$ is approximately $(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y})\cdot (\text{area inside $\gamma_i$)}$. Adding these up gives, approximately, $\iint_R (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y})\,dx\,dy$ (and if you take a limit as the curves $\gamma_i$ shrink, the word "approximately" goes away). So, $\int_{\gamma} \mathbf{F} = \iint_R (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y})\,dx\,dy$—this is Green's theorem. In particular, if $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$, the integral of $\mathbf{F}$ around $\gamma$ is $0$, which means $\mathbf{F}$ is conservative.

Now there's an immediate problem when the domain of $\mathbf{F}$ isn't simply connected: if $\gamma$ goes around a hole, then you can't fill in the region enclosed by it with little closed curves (at least not ones you can integrate $\mathbf{F}$ along).

(It's possible to turn this bug into a feature, i.e. to quantify the discrepancy between "$\mathbf{F}$ is conservative" and "$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$" as a way of seeing what sort of holes your domain has. This is the idea of de Rham cohomology, which a couple of people have mentioned already.)

Comment: Did you mean $\partial Q/\partial x - \partial P /\partial y$?

Comment: Yes, thanks--the lesson is to always mind your P's and Q's...

Answer (score 3):

As commented by dafinguzman openness is required to have well defined partial derivatives. At a point of he boundary it might be tricky to define a partial derivative.

As for simply connected, consider the field
$$
(P,Q)=\Bigl(-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\Bigr),\quad (x,y)\ne(0,0).
$$
It satisfies
$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}
$$
but is not conservative. The line integral along a circle centered at $(0,0)$ is not equal to $0$.

Comment: I parametrized the curve using $<acost, asint>$ from $t = 0$ to $t = 2\pi$ and then evaluated the line integral $\int F \cdot dr$. The result was actually 0. I can see what you imply at, however: that there are scenarios in which the field might not be conservative, despite $\frac{\delta P}{\delta y} = \frac{\delta Q}{\delta x}$. These scenarios occur when the region isn't simply connected. Is there some intuitive, more general way to understand this however? anomaly summarized an account that give a rigorous approach to proving this.  Is there something simpler?

Comment: There was a typo. I have corrected the definition of the field. The example is related to the impossibility of defining a continuous polar angle in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. If you know some complex analysis, you will note that the field components are the real and imaginary parts of $1/z$, and $1/z$ has no primitive on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @Muno Intuitively the argument is 'if there's a hole, your vector field can travel around the hole'.  Going much beyond that puts you square in the realm of cohomology, and while there's a lot to learn there, the basics aren't too bad: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology